# Difficulty with static, initializing, drivers, and returning null

Tags: java, arraylist, null

I've been working on this project to familiarize myself with some driver class stuff.

So I have an arraylist that I've populated with strings and I am attempting to access that in my driver class. I had some advice by using a different method to initialize the strings and calling that in my main and at the same time, calling a method in the driver class where it will get my arraylist. However, this only returns null despite the fact that it should all be initialized. What is going wrong, all help is appreciated.

Here's my original class:

```
    static ArrayList <String> Numbers;

public static void initializeStrings(){
         Numbers = new ArrayList <String>(); 
            Numbers.add("one");
            Numbers.add("two");
            Numbers.add("three");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        OriginalClass.initializeStrings();
        Driver.getting();
    }
```

And here's my driver class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getting(); 
}
public static void getting() {

        System.out.println(OriginalClass.getMouseList());
    }
```

Comment: You should never have 2 main methods, I would first try removing the one NOT in the driver class and attempting to print those a different way

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the array list is only initialized when the main method of that class is called...

otherwise you get a null reference...
call directly the `OriginalClass.initializeStrings();` in the driver class instead

## Example:

... in the driver class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OriginalClass.initializeStrings();
    getting(); 
}
```